# Collision detection between two character controllers

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am new to Unity and scripting. I have two players and both are using a character controller. I have done this thing

- I have used onControllerColliderHit function.
- I have print the name like this gameobj.name.
- It will show the name of the object that it hit

But the problem is it passes through it. I want that it's not able to pass through it and it will behave just like rigid bodies have. Like there must be effect of force through which  second player hit it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-CharacterController.html). CharacterController as is has no `RigidBody` attached:

> The Character Controller is mainly used for third-person or
>   first-person player control that does not make use of Rigidbody
>   physics.

Basically `CharacterController` is only a `Collisor` designed for preventing compenetration between the character and objects in the scene, but doesn't work as you expect when the collision occurs between 2 `CharacterControllers`.

Particularly:

> The Controller does not react to forces on its own and it does not
>   automatically push Rigidbodies away.

Like shown in [OnControllerColliderHit](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html) documentation you can manually handle the collision when this occurs. For example you can push away from each other the character controller object when they collide since you have the move direction:

```
Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
transform.Translate (-pushDir * offset);
```